# Parsing JSON in EE tag

Tags: templates, variable, preload-replace, brilliantretail

We have a BrilliantRetail cart and I'm adding JSON data into an attribute named itemJSON.
In the cart template, we loop through the items in the cart using the {items}{/items} tag and I need to show certain values from the JSON stored in the attribute.

Using the

```
{itemJSON}
```

tag shows the full JSON. I only want some of the values stored there without having to use PHP in my template. Is this doable? Doing it like either of these fails, it shows the tag, instead:

```
{itemJSON->SP->FN}
{itemJSON.SP.FN}
```

Would there be a way to use preload_replace to do this?

**Edited->showing code:**
This doesn't seem to be working correctly:

```
$json = json_decode($this->EE->TMPL->fetch_param("json"), true);
$values["StudentName"]    = $json["ShortParticipants"][0]["FirstName"];
$values["CEState"]        = $json["ShortParticipants"][0]["CEInfo"]["CEState"];
$values["CENameOnLic"]    = $json["ShortParticipants"][0]["CEInfo"]["CEFirstName"]." ".$json["ShortParticipants"][0]["CEInfo"]["CELastName"];
$values["CELicencelabel"] = $json["ShortParticipants"][0]["CEInfo"]["CELicenseText"];
$values["CELicenseNum"]   = $json["ShortParticipants"][0]["CEInfo"]["CELicense"];
$values["CEHours"]        = $json["ShortParticipants"][0]["CEInfo"]["Hours"];
$values["course_text"]    = file_get_contents("http://".$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]."/files/getCourseText.php?EventCode=".$json["eventcode"]."&Cart=yes");

$vars = array((array) $values);

$this->return_data = $this->EE->TMPL->parse_variables($this->EE->TMPL->tagdata, $vars);
```

Also, in using the tag like you show:

```
{exp:tnajson json="{itemJSON}"}
    {if sku == "CE_FEE"}
    <i>CE For Student: {StudentName}</i><br />
    Course: {course_text}<br />
    <hr style="color: #D9DDE3; background-color: #D9DDE3; margin-bottom: 5px;" />
    CE State: {CEState}<br />
    Name On License: {CENameOnLic}<br />
    {CELicencelabel}: {CELicenseNum}<br />
    Hours: {CEHours}<br />  
    {if:else}
    <i>For Student: {StudentName}</i><br />
    {course_text}
    {/if}
{/exp:tnajson}
```

It shows this:

```
}}"}
```

And then none of the values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what existing solution there are, but I would just create a real simple plugin with [pkg.io](http://pkg.io).

Basically, your constructor method would look like this:

```
public function constructor()
{
    $json = json_encode($this->EE->TMPL->fetch_param('json'));

    // Now you need to parse the JSON object. This will be unique
    // depending on what your JSON object looks like.
    // This example assumes you have an object 1 level deep and it needs
    // converted to an indexed associated array.

    $vars = array((array) $json);

    $this->return_data = $this->EE->TMPL->parse_variables($this->EE->TMPL->tagdata, $vars);
}
```

Your template tags will look like this:

```
{exp:your_plugin json="{itemJSON}"}
    {your_obj_property_name_1}
    {your_obj_property_name_2}
    {your_obj_property_name_3}
{/exp:your_plugin}
```

Comment: Explain this: $vars = array((array) $json);

Comment: That just converts and object into an associated array, and then inserts it into another array. This is known as an "indexed associative array". So you end up with an array of associative arrays. Alternatively, you can use $this->EE->TMPL->parse_variables_row() which just accepts an associative array (without an indexed array). http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/usage/template.html#parsing-variables

Comment: It's not working as I expected, see edits to original.

Comment: TBH, I can't say for why sure what it's not parsing. It looks correct as far as I can tell. Add  var_dump($vars);exit(); right before you send it to parser. See if your values are correct. Another place to check would be to ensure the $json variable has the expected values. It seems to be correct, or I would think there would be PHP errors denoting that.

Comment: I think it may have to do with the way the {itemJSON} is being sent to the plugin.

Comment: It's possible you will need to create another tag to pass the JSON using the tagdata. This would be the "setter", and within the above method you would "get" that data from memory. Using flash storage or some other EE method.

Comment: Not exactly sure what you are talking about.

Comment: When I var_dump the $json variable in the plugin, it is null.

Comment: I think that the double quotes in the JSON is the cause. How would I escape that?

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and accept this and post another question.

Comment: Hello it did not work for me, have you solved this ?